# How to send sms without pending intent in android?

Tags: android, sms, android-pendingintent

I want to send sms from an android device I used this code for it;

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
ViewPagerFragmentActivity.class), 0);
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
```

But this opens my `ViewPagerFragmentActivity` continuously on top. How can I manipulate my code to not allow this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own problem

```
private void prepareandsendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

with this manipulation.